# How to change color of checkbox drawable specified in xml?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat

My Checkbox's background is specified via drawable xml and I want to change the color of these items via code. Different control in Android seems to have different ways to set its color.

```
<Checkbox android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox" />
```

In drawable/custom_checkbox.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Most answers on SO stop at the solution above. I am able to change the color via the following code but this code will not work in certain API level (e.g. level 17).  I would like something that works across the board.

```
Drawable d = DrawableCompat.wrap(checkbox.getBackground());
DrawableCompat.setTint(d, newColor);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, TabLayout icon color doesn't change when dragging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475790/android-tablayout-icon-color-doesnt-change-when-dragging)

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate.  I am asking about Checkbox, not tab.  Solution also has layer-list in its example, which I don't.

Comment: Yes it is. The accepted answer in this thread shows, how to tint the state drawable on all API levels.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39561185/6756523) helps you.

and i think this: `android:buttonTint="@color/mybrown"` is a simple way

Comment: This solution won't work for API level 17 (or possibly anything below API level 21).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Drawable d = DrawableCompat.wrap(checkbox.getBackground());
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(d, newColor);

    } else {
        d.mutate().setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
```